# My app icon is not showing on some devices - why?

Tags: java, android, icons

I have an app icon saved in drawable as an xml file, it shows on most devices but some Huawei devices show the default launcher icon instead. This is my code in manifest

```
android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon" 
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: Hmm, okay let me try that

Comment: @Prajwal W it worked thanks. It won't disturb how the icon appears on other devices will it?

Comment: no because for different api devices, the devices either uses round icon or default size icons based on the android version. It wont affect other devices!
Please do select the answer as accepted so that others can know the solution.

Comment: How do you accept the answer for a comment, I just click the up arrow?

Comment: Check the answer I hv added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Huaweii requires round launcher icon. Add your app icon image within the android:roundIcon attribute! The reason why you get the default android icon is because you are calling it in your android:roundIcon attribute! –

For different api devices, the devices either uses round icon or default size icons based on the android version. It wont affect other devices! Please do select the answer as accepted so that others can know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have added all the drawables to every dpi levels like below.
[[image]]
Or the best practices is to use vector image, then you can reduce the size of application.
just import the .svg as xml file. just drag and drop into resource manager.) 
refer: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

generate as assets: 
[image]

Comment: Is it a must the icon should be png?

Comment: My icon is in the form of an xml file

Comment: import xml file from vector as Asset file and generate the icon from it. because we have to give every shapes of the icons for the App icon. if you are using svg no need give multiple dpis.
in menifest add 
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_round"